# Mock namespace function (Mocha, sinon, es6)

Tags: ecmascript-6, mocha.js, sinon

I have a util module consisting of the following namespaced exports

```
    // utils.js
    export const getWindowLocation(){window.location}
    export const func2(){getWindowLocation().href = ....}
```

I would like to stub/override getWindowLocation in my mocha test

```
//UtilTest.js
import * as utils from "src/js/utils/utils";
import sinon from "sinon";
describe("Utils", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
         sinon.stub(utils, "getWindowLocation").returns({});      
    });
....
```

The stub seems not to be overriding my method. I am not sure if namespaced function should be treated differently?

Thank you,

Comment: They aren't namespaced. They are exports. Native ES module exports are read-only. This is unnecessary so with bundling systems. This totally depends on your environment,

Comment: Try modifying the stub statement to
`sinon.stub(utils.prototype, "getWindowLocation").returns({})`